# Como utilizar o token para validar o login de um usuário Django Rest Framework

Tags: api, django, login, token, django-rest-framework

Olá, estou meio perdido quanto a autenticação de um usuário pelo django-rest-framework, eu estava seguindo o tutorial do canal CodingEntrepreneurs no video 32 do Blog API (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXQqNtjNJc) ele explica como fazer a autenticação do usuário via token com django-rest-jwt, porém achei muito confuso.. e la vai a pergunta:

1 - Como utilizo o token para permitir acesso do usuário (login) e para que ele consiga consumir todas as minhas APIs no mobile?? O meu projeto está igual ao do tutorial (parte da api)

**serializers.py**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)
username = CharField(label='Código do Usuário',
                     allow_blank=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'token']
    extra_kwargs = {'password':
                    {'write_only': True
                     }
                    }

def validate(self, data):
    user_obj = None
    username = data.get('username', None)
    password = data['password']
    if not username:
        raise ValidationError('Insira o Código de Usuário!')

    user = User.objects.filter(
        Q(username=username)
    ).distinct()
    if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
        user_obj = user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError('Esse Código de Usuário não é válido!')

    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError('Credenciais Incorretas!')

        data['token'] = 'Some token Here'

    return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma view para o seu login (essa view já vem "pronta" graças ao framework, porém caso você queria personalizar você pode.)
'**obtain_jwt_token**' vai fazer login e retornar um token ela espera os parametros no post {'username': string, 'password': string}

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class UserLogin(APIView):
permission_classes = ()
authentication_classes = ()

def post(self, request):
    # caso queria fazer alguma personalização faça aqui
    return obtain_jwt_token(request)
```

Crie uma url para o seu login.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from core.perfil.api UserLogin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', UserLogin.as_view()),
]
```

Para testar pode usar o postman[image: Resultado:]

Perceba que minha url ficou **/api/perfil/login/**, não necessariamente sua rota será a mesma. Você configurará a sua no arquivo de urls. (acredito que você já saiba disso).

---

EDIT: Vou explicar como ter um retorno customizado para a função **obtain_jwt_token**

No seu arquivo de configuração do Django (**settings.py**) você pode passar como parâmetro uma função própria para sobrescrever o retorno padrão:

```
# INFORMAÇÕES DO CONTROLE DE API
JWT_AUTH = {'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':'core.perfil.serializers.minha_funcao',}
```

Perceba que no exemplo que dei a minha função esta localizada no arquivo de serializers que ficar na pasta core/perfil/serializers. No seu caso você pode colocar onde quiser.

E a "minha_funcao" pode ser por exemplo:

```
def minha_funcao(token, user=None, request=None):
  return {
      'token': token,
      'username': user.username,
      'nome': user.first_name,
  }
```

Comment: Como faço para personalizar meu token, para passar as informações que eu quiser, por exemplo por default ele passa (user_id,username,e-mail,exp..) como faço para ele passar para o token por exemplo a imagem do user e outras informações do cadastro do usuário?? para que eu possa 'decodar' depois

Comment: Eu dei uma editada, vê se te ajuda!